# Viewing multicast iptv via wifi from mikrotik router RB2011

Tags: wireless-networking, router, iptv, mikrotik-routeros

I would like to view multicast iptv stream via wifi from my mikrotik router, but couldn't find such settings in it.

I've found suggestions to install udproxy on the router. This is not possible because of a proprietary RouterOS on the device.

Is there some other way to get multicast streaming via wifi from mikrotik?

The RouterOS version is 6.29.1

The full board name is RB2011UAS-2HnD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up IGMP proxy and have a look at the multicast helper setting
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Wireless

Mikrotik doesn't support IGMP snooping so be prepared that the wifi connection will be flooded when some other port in bridge is using multicast

Comment: Isn´t switching channels a couple of times enough to start the flooding? I could never get multicast over WiFi to work without IGMP snooping.

Comment: Yes,until a timeout stops the multicast flows from the previous IPs. Multicast over Wifi is a bad idea, you have packetloss,and you are flooding the shared medium, unlike cable.